# Canvas getImageData not getting the target area

Tags: javascript, canvas, putimagedata

I cannot seem to to copy image data from a specific area on a canvas.

I can paint a rectangle around the area but when I use getImageData it caputures a different area.

I am trying to capture the grey box labelled click using

let sweepImgData = ctx.getImageData(300,250 ,100, 20);

But when I then use:

ctx.putImageData(sweepImgData, 75, 75);

It shows a blank box.

Can anyone please put me out of my misery?

https://jsfiddle.net/piersheriotwalker/67eLvg1t/53/

```
   var ctx = document.getElementById("canv").getContext("2d");
    
    let sweepImgData = ctx.getImageData(300,250 ,100, 20);

    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0 , ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

    ctx.putImageData(sweepImgData, 75, 75);
```

Comment: What did you expect to get, when copying an area outside of the canvas? Don't set the dimensions of the canvas using CSS, use `width` and `height` attributes of the canvas instead.

Comment: Exactly the absolute coordinates are outside, the default size of the canvas is much smaller, CSS doesn't affect to the amount of the pixels in the canvas, it just stretches the existing pixels. See [a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/9wLsnaf7/).

Comment: Yes you are right I now see I havent added the image to the canvas first. Sorry I realise that I have set the fiddle up incorrectly I will fix the fiddle then ask again

Comment: Teemu Thank you very much for your help